# JavaScript: Repeat a function X times at I intervals

Tags: javascript

I've written a general purpose repeat function which allows you to repeat a callback function X times separated by I intervals with the option to start immediately or after the interval. It can also default to just looping infinitely, which is what `setInterval` does. Is there a better approach, or any improvements people can provide? Make sure to comment out all but one of the examples :)

```
function repeatXI(callback, interval, repeat, immediate) {
    repeat = typeof repeat == 'undefined' ? -1 : repeat;
    interval = interval <= 0 ? 1000 : interval;
    immediate = typeof immediate == 'undefined' ? false : immediate;
    var offset = immediate ? 0 : 1;
    var id = null;
    if (repeat > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
            id = setTimeout(callback, interval * (i + offset));
        }
    } else {
        id = setInterval(callback, interval);
    }
    return id;
}

// Example
var someFunc = function () {console.log(1);}

// Repeats forever, 1 second apart
repeatXI(someFunc, 1000);
// Repeats 10 times, 1 second apart, beginning after 1 second
repeatXI(someFunc, 1000, 10);
// Same as above, but beginning now
repeatXI(someFunc, 1000, 10, true);
```

Comment: Also good to note the difference in setTimeout and setInterval - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval

Answer (score 6):

I don't see anything problematic with your code, but just for fun, here are some alternative approaches to various parts of the code. It's 100% DRY, and functionally identical to the original.

```
function repeatXI(callback, interval, repeats, immediate) {
  var timer, trigger;
  trigger = function () {
    callback();
    --repeats || clearInterval(timer);
  };

  interval = interval <= 0 ? 1000 : interval; // default: 1000ms
  repeats  = parseInt(repeats, 10) || 0;      // default: repeat forever
  timer    = setInterval(trigger, interval);

  if( !!immediate ) { // Coerce boolean
    trigger();
  }
}
```

**[And here's a jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NdhCR/)**

If you want, you can return `timer` from the function (as I do in the demo), so you can clear it (i.e. cancel the repeater) elsewhere in your code.

Regardless of the implementation-specifics it's worth noting that timers are unreliable at the best of times (since JS is single-threaded). Depending on your needs it may not be a good idea to set *n* timeouts at `n * interval` as you do for finite repeats. If a few of the timeouts get blocked long enough, they'll all queue up, and fire at once, once the thread clears. With `setInterval` though, you're guaranteed that there'll be *at least* `interval` time between the callbacks.

So it depends on your needs how you want to implement it.

Comment: good point regarding the intervals!

Comment: @AramKocharyan No prob. Don't forget to click the checkmark on mine or Joseph's answer - whichever one you think helped the most

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty much commented in the code. The usage is still the same as the one you used. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J8Umt/).

```
function repeatXI(callback, interval, repetitions, immediate) {

    //general purpose repeater function
    function repeater(repetitions) {
        if (repetitions >= 0) {

            //use call or apply so we can specify "this"
            callback.call(this);

            //repeat
            setTimeout(function() {

                //the idea of passing the repetition count replaces the loop
                //the -- means that the initial iteration turns the repeat to -1
                //since the condition runs when >=0 repetitions
                repeater(--repetitions);
            }, interval);
        }
    }

    //set defaults using ||
    //|| means "use this value OR the default"
    //if you want to be strict, you can do type checks instead
    repetitions = repetitions || 0;
    interval = interval || 1000;

    //if immediate, call instantly, else, delay
    if (immediate) {
        console.log('immediate');
        repeater(--repetitions);
    } else {
        console.log('delayed');
        setTimeout(function() {
            repeater(--repetitions);
        }, interval);
    }
}
```

Witout comments and packed:

```
function repeatXI(callback, interval, repetitions, immediate) {
    function repeater(repetitions) {
        if (repetitions >= 0) {
            callback.call(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                repeater(--repetitions)
            }, interval)
        }
    }
    repetitions = repetitions || 0;
    interval = interval || 1000;
    if (immediate) {
        repeater(--repetitions)
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            repeater(--repetitions)
        }, interval)
    }
}
```